# Python: a special 2d array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I need to make a 2D array of n by n which looks like the following

lets take n equals 5 for example

```
n = 5
A = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],[2,3,4,5,6],[3,4,5,6,7], [4,5,6,7,8], [5,6,7,8,9]])
```

I have no clue how to do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a 1d sequence array first and then do an outer addition with itself:

```
a = np.arange(5)
np.add.outer(a, a) + 1

#[[1 2 3 4 5]
# [2 3 4 5 6]
# [3 4 5 6 7]
# [4 5 6 7 8]
# [5 6 7 8 9]]
```

Or `a + a[:, None] + 1` gives same result.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can first create a list of lists first and then wrap it in numpy array later as well.

```py
n = 5
a = [list(range(i,i+n)) for i in range(1,n+1)]
print(a)
```

Gives the following

```py
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
```

You can change n to other values and the result will still be correct. For example for n = 7 ..

```py
n = 7
a = [list(range(i,i+n)) for i in range(1,n+1)]
print(a)
```

Gives

```py
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]]
```

Now that you have a you can get A by simply saying

```py
A = np.array(a)
```